# configure classpath in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I configure the classpath so I can use this code without errors

```
GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
ctx.load("classpath:appContext/messageSource.xml");
```

the error I get now is

```
Exception in thread "main" 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [messageSource.xml]; 
nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource 
[messageSource.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Comment: yes actually I'm using springsources Spring tool Suite which comes with maven

Comment: here comes the answer.. this will work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick `Build Path > Use as Source Folder` an apply it to the `appContext` folder. I believe Eclipse adds an entry in the project's `.classpath` file, which is in your best interest.